# Add toolbar with app name android

Tags: android

i'm a novice android developer and i'v noticed that some new activities have the name of my app on the toolbar, but when i create the XML and link it with the java class, the toolbar dissapear on this new view.

How do i add the toolbar or turn this on to all the activities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i have noticed that the default activity has extended `AppCompatActivity` that gives the ability to use toolbar, if you extends only `Activity`, this wont add the toolbar by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a default toolbar layout and include it to your layout.

toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/white">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And an example to use it :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
</LinearLayout>
```